# Ignore duplicate key upon insert with PDO

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, pdo

Is there a generic way to `INSERT IGNORE` with PDO that will work on all database drivers?

If not, is it fair to assume the following would work:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO link_table (id1, id2) VALUES (:id1, :id2)");
    $stmt->execute(array( ':id1' => $id1, ':id2' => $id2 ));
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // Thanks to comment by Mike:

    // Re-throw exception if it wasn't a constraint violation.
    if ($ex->getCode() != 23000)
        throw $ex;
}
```

Comment: @Haim Evgi from what I read `INSERT IGNORE INTO` is a non standard SQL feature that only works with MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK  no there is not a generic version that will work with all database drivers.  `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` are specific to MySQL.

Checking for an existing record by selecting it first, or deleting an existing record and re-inserting are both prone to problems, including race conditions and possible foreign key constraint violations or cascading deletes.

I think your approach is probably the safest.  You can always [check the error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) if you want to determine the cause of the exception - see:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jenut/ch08_06.htm

I think you might want to check for code 23000.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would probably work, but there are other things that can go wrong while executing a PDO statement. You will want to check if you really receive a constraint violation, and even if it's not a different kind (for example, you could also receive a foreign key violation when inserting a pair of values that doesn't have corresponding rows in one of the referenced tables). AFAIK, there is no cross-DBMS way to achieve this though.

For DBMSes that support transactions (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL to some extent, ...), here's a different approach:

1. start transaction
2. delete all rows that match the row to be inserted (deleting zero or one rows)
3. insert
4. commit